# how to set background color + opacity in table view cell + style is grouped

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i have one `tableview` with style grouped. in this i set background color `clearcolor`

like this , `cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor blackColor];`
now i want this cell transparent. may be i can do this with opacity. but in this how can i set opacity.

i want same like this for cell background >>

[image]

here opacity . how can i do same this by coding in cell background ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `cell.alpha = 0;` then your cell is invisible but all textLabels etc. to.
If you want only the cell.backgroundColor a bit transparent you can use
`cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0. green:0.39 blue:0.106 alpha:0.]`

Comment: i want black color in background + transparent cell.

Comment: `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0. green:0.39 blue:0.106 alpha:0.5]` the exact values for red, green and blue can you get with the "DigitalColor" App on your Mac.  
their value is between 0.0 and 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above answer. You can achieve transparency by simply setting cell's contentView alpha.

```
cell.backgroundColor = .black
cell.contentView.alpha = 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

//.  Add this to viewdidload()

```
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    tableView.alpha = 0.65
```